# Вылетает Android Studio при открытии xml файлов

Tags: java

При открытии файлов .xml  в пакете res (некоторых из них, а именно отвечающих за отрисовку интерфейса).
Открытый файл .xml вызывает окно визуализатора, который во время инициализации(но это не точно, т.к. вылет происходит до момента ее окончания), AS вылетает на desktop(закрывается).
При этом происходит рассинхронизация с groodle файлами самого проекта(после перезахода в AS).
log пуст...
[image: на скрине для наглядности описаное окно визуализации]

Answer (score 0):

Я могу быть не прав, но возможно дело в самом Android Studio. Попробуйте переустановить его, либо вместо него поставить Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Не исключено, вопрос переустановки не помогает, траил много раз разными способами. Idea установлена, плагин установил, но опять казус,  не синхронизируется с grodle пытался решить вопрос, но безуспешно. Отчаялся, и прошу помощи у опытных девелоперов. Если все же дело в некорректной установке AS, то, возможно та же ошибка и при установке плагина в Idea, не учитывая невозможность синхронизироваться с grodle, при этом, вопрос открыт.